# Incorrect values are passed on click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, materialize

On click of a button the code will check that "select all" is selected or individually selected. Now the problem is if one selects any "select all" checkbox and if then unchecked any option, then these unchecked values are passed instead of checked ones.

```
 $("#next").click(function () {
   debugger

   $(".show").show();
   $("#next").hide();

   if ($('.checkbox2 ul.dropdown-content li input[type=checkbox]').first().is(':checked') == true){
     $.each(budata, function (key, value) {
       arr.push(key);
     });

   }else {
     debugger
     arr = $('option[name=BU]:checked').map(function () { 
       return this.value;
     }).get();
   }
   var bu = arr.join(',');
```

HTML CODE

```
<div class="checkbox2">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select id="dropdown1" multiple>
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select BU</option>
    </select>
    <label>BU</label>
  </div>
 </div>
```

AJAX CALl for BU values(Checkbox values)

```
var data = {};
data.dateFrom = $("#dateFrom").val();
data.BU = $("#dropdown1").val();
data.Location = $("#Location").val();
data.Type = $("#dropdown").val();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: ServiceURL + 'MaterialClearance/getBU/',
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {

    $('#dropdown1').html('<option id="selectall" name="selectall" value="selectall" ">(Select All)</option>');
    if (data.length > 0) {

      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        budata[data[i].BU] = 0;
        $('#dropdown1').append('<option name="BU" value="' + data[i].BU + '">' + data[i].BU + '</option>')
      }
    }
    $('#dropdown1').material_select();
  }
});
```

CODE for select all nd individual checked checkbox

```
$('.checkbox2 ul.dropdown-content li').click(function () {
  debugger
  if ($('.checkbox2 ul.dropdown-content li').first().is(".selected")) {
    $('.checkbox2 ul.dropdown-content li:not(:first-child)').each(function (index) {
      $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $('.checkbox2 ul.dropdown-content li').first().find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked"));
    });
  }
  else {
    alert($('option[name=BU]:checked'));
    $('.checkbox2 ul.dropdown-content li input[type=checkbox]').first().prop("checked", false);
    alert($('option[name=BU]:checked'));
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be easier to suggest something if you post your HTML.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i've edited

Comment: There is no `checkbox` in that markup... Only a `<select>` and some `<div>`. Therefore, It's unclear why you expect a `:checked` state...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette the values for checkbox come from the database

Comment: I can't imagine what that code can be... And it seems to be a confusion about what a [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) is...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Now can u suggest?

Comment: okay... Am I close to what you have in this [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LQJEOb?editors=1011)?

Comment: yes, budata is object(contains all the values initially). in that if one select (select all) option that in "arr" array all value is pushed.-@LouysPatriceBessette